# Can you hide certain react fragments rendered by array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, search

**Summary**

I have about 100 react fragments loaded into an array, and then passed to my react render method. I'm trying to implement a search bar so a user can quickly search for certain titles. In my case, here's what each element in my array looks like:

```
<Grid item md={10} style={{alignContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', display: 'all'}}>
  <Card data={json[item]} title={item} onClick={that.props.install} result={testResult} 
</Grid>
```

Each title looks someting like **20.0.15**, **20.0.16**, **20.0.20**, etc etc. So if a user entered **20.0.1**, given only the above, I'd want to just hide the latter.

**Attempts**

I've done the quick and dirty way of just straight up deleting an entry after looping through the titles and then setStating a new array. But I'm curious if theres a better way. You'll notice i have a `display: 'all'` in my JSX for the grid. When set to none, it will hide that element. Is there a way to programatically set that value? I've tried digging into the react element and manually setting it, but that gives the following error: `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'display' of object '#<Object>'`

The code that produced this error:
`this.state.cardArray[i].props.style.display = 'none';`

Is there a cleaner way to simply hide react fragments in an array?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not filtering the data *before* building the React components?

Comment: Have you tried to filter the array? Having your render logic would be useful.

Comment: @Robfz Just looked into array.filter and got it working pretty nicely. thanks for the tip!

Comment: @coreyward i'm not filtering it before because it's a text entry search bar. Upon render, nothing has been entered, so I'm rendering all the data. Once the user inputs something, then I would have to filter.

Comment: @TechyTy I don't mean filtering the user input, I mean the data that you're saying is already an array of React Fragments that are being passed in as props.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can programatically change the `display` value. Here is an example using a ternary operator:

```
<Grid item md={10} display={title.includes(searchQuery) ? "all" : "none"}>
  <Card title={title}/>
</Grid>
```

This will conditionally set the `display` property to show titles that match the user's `searchQuery`.

Comment: This looks pretty clean. I'll have to test this out against the other method mentioned. Thanks!